# Docker Container is started but not ruuning

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, containers

Following is my Docker compose file. I have used the Jenkins images to install jenkins. Within same file,I have define another container from which I can SSH and connect with Jenkins server.

Docker Compose File

```
version: '3'
services: 
  jenkins:
    container_name: jenkins
    image: jenkins/jenkins
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - "$PWD/jenkins_home:/var/jenkins_home"
    networks:
      - net
  remote_host:
    container_name: remote-host
    image: remote-host
    build:
      context: centos
    networks:
      - net
networks:
  net:
```

Created another folder name Centos and created Dockerfile within it.

```
FROM centos:7

RUN yum -y install openssh-server

RUN useradd remote_user && \
    echo remote_user:1234 | chpasswd && \
    mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ssh

COPY remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized-key

RUN chown remote_user:remote_user -R /home/remote_user/.ssh && \
    chmod 600 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized-key

RUN /usr/sbin/sshd-keygen 

CMD /usr/sbin/ssh -D
```

I ran following command
**docker-compose build**

Output

```
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                         0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 32B                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/centos:7                                                                                                  0.7s
 => [1/6] FROM docker.io/library/centos:7@sha256:c73f515d06b0fa07bb18d8202035e739a494ce760aa73129f60f4bf2bd22b407                                            0.0s
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                            0.0s
 => => transferring context: 36B                                                                                                                             0.0s
 => CACHED [2/6] RUN yum -y install openssh-server                                                                                                           0.0s
 => CACHED [3/6] RUN useradd remote_user &&     echo remote_user:1234 | chpasswd &&     mkdir /home/remote_user/.ssh &&     chmod 700 /home/remote_user/.ss  0.0s
 => CACHED [4/6] COPY remote-key.pub /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized-key                                                                                   0.0s
 => CACHED [5/6] RUN chown remote_user:remote_user -R /home/remote_user/.ssh &&     chmod 600 /home/remote_user/.ssh/authorized-key                          0.0s
 => CACHED [6/6] RUN /usr/sbin/sshd-keygen                                                                                                                   0.0s
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                      0.0s
 => => writing image sha256:fcaaebf103d6674134a68c23f92e2946b9395e2a970b3c2e78c59b9a18fec8be                                                                 0.0s
 => => naming to docker.io/library/remote-host
```

then I ran following command
**docker-compose up -d**

Output

```
[+] Running 2/2
 ⠿ Container jenkins      Running                                                                                                                            0.0s
 ⠿ Container remote-host  Started
```

When I run **docker images**, I can see remote-host

```
REPOSITORY        TAG       IMAGE ID       CREATED        SIZE
remote-host       latest    fcaaebf103d6   25 hours ago   367MB
jenkins/jenkins   latest    97d23cbbfa56   5 days ago     463MB
```

but when I run **docker ps**, I do not see the running container.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED        STATUS        PORTS                               NAMES
06aa0ceabb18   jenkins/jenkins   "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   39 hours ago   Up 37 hours   0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 50000/tcp   jenkins
```

**docker ps -a**

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE             COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS                       PORTS                               NAMES
dbd2c2b9cecb   jenkins/jenkins   "/sbin/tini -- /usr/…"   30 minutes ago   Up 30 minutes                0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp, 50000/tcp   jenkins
812216a3c8e9   remote-host       "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sb…"   30 minutes ago   Exited (127) 7 minutes ago
```

Can someone tell me where did I make mistake?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to pull the logs from the container:

```
docker logs 812216a3c8e9
```

Where `812216a3c8e9` is your container ID. Exit code 127 normally means Docker not is able to execute your entrypoint (in your case: `CMD /usr/sbin/ssh -D`)